# Building a SignalR / Knockout dashboard with guaranteed messaging

Tags: c#, asp.net, knockout.js, signalr, real-time

I'm looking into replacing a monitoring dashboard at our company using real-time messaging.

### The Old Concept:

At our company we have a dashboard that displays the (rather detailed) status of over 700 physical machines, plus added meta-information. It was built about 1,5 years ago by a colleague of mine in ASP.NET Web Forms (which I don't like) to enable dispatchers to coordinate where our technicians should go to fix problems (the machines are located in various geographical locations).

Unfortunately, the app uses a 30-second complete page auto-refresh with a big query behind it. It's slow and it completely resets your view (as I said, the dashboard contains over 700+ machines). Personally I would like to change this. It is extremely annoying to use. Our dispatchers have learned to live with this, but I think they deserve better.

### The New Concept:

I want to display the same content on a new dashboard, but with real-time updates and "message" log. At our company we work for about 90% on a MS stack, so I plan on using ASP.NET MVC, SignalR, SQL Server and Knockout.

### What I currently have

Take a look at this simple diagram:

```
 +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+ +----+            
 | PC | | PC | | PC | | PC | | PC | | PC | | PC | ... ...    
 +--+-+ +--+-+ +-+--+ +--+-+ +--+-+ +--+-+ +--+-+            
    |      |     |       |      |      |      |              
    |   +--+  +--+  +----+    <-+    <-+    <-+              
    |   |     |     |                                        
+---v---v-----v-----v+         +-----------------------+     
|                    | TCP/IP  |                       |     
| Monitoring Backend +--------->  Data Enrichment App  |     
|                    |         |                       |     
+--------------------+         +---------+-------------+     
                                         |                   
          +------------------------------+        +---------+
          |                                       |         |
          |                +----------------+     |         |
    +-----v-----+---------->    DB Proxy    +----->  S Q L  |
    |           | PUB/SUB  +----------------+     |         |
    |   Redis   |                                 |         |
    |           |          +----------------+     +---------+
    +-----------+          |     TO BE...   |                
                           +----------------+
```

- I created a little "Data enrichment app" that receives events from the monitoring backend over TCP/IP and adds additional business data to the event (For example, the location of the devices, a descriptive name alongside the hostname, a humn-readable translation of the alert, etc.) that is not contained in the monitoring system.
- Enriched events are sent from the app to Redis. I did this so other applications can hook into Redis as a subscriber, since the data I'm outputting here is superior and more readable than what the monitoring backend sends out.
- Currently the only thing PUB/SUB-ing to Redis is a DB proxy that listens for incoming events and sends those to the Database (SQL Server), which I already use for historical reporting purposes, but currently only contains rather simplistic data.

The idea here is to subscribe a SignalR Hub to the Redis backend in my ASP.NET application to fire events over to the client. (That's the **TO BE** part)

### The Problem:

The idea is that when the client navigates to the dashboard URL, the initial overview is populated by the status data that's in the SQL backend. Afterwards, events are received through SignalR and the view is updated by changing Knockout properties.

However, should a client get disconnected (say, by sleeping his laptop when walking from meeting room to meeting room) he misses messages from the SignalR hub, and his dashboard view is no longer correct!

Possible solutions would be:

1. *Sending the complete status of every device through SignalR on every event change:* This is impossible because of the huge amount of data I would have to send over the wire. (I'm guessing at least 12,000 records of JSON data)
2. *Forcing a complete refresh after detecting a timed-out connection*: I have no idea how to implement this using SignalR :(
3. ... ?

What is the recommended approach to dealing with Real-time, push-based data and guaranteeing that data arrives? Or how would I deal with recovering from a timed-out connections? Or is the idea of making this real-time crazy?

**Disclaimer:** I'm a system engineer, not a profession programmer. This is my first real-time web app. Other questions regarding SignalR usually don't deal with large amounts of data like this.

Comment: Best ASCII picture I have seen in a while.

Comment: Implement a simple mechanism that will make it possible for you to figure out if the messages has been missed (e.g. in each message send a message number. If the difference between the previous and the current message is greater than 1 you would know you missed some messages). if a message has been missed refresh the page.

Comment: @Pawel You mean implement a (Square wheel) Message Queue?

Comment: @Aron - No. I was thinking just about numbering SignalR messages so that you can detect that you miss a message and in which case you would get the content using different means (e.g. an HTTP request).

Comment: @Pawel its a naive implementation of the programming pattern known as Message Queue. Its a thing, look it up.

Comment: My impression is that Message Queue is much broader than that...

Comment: @Pawel that is also my point. Message Queues are a RELIABLE  IPC FIFO. There is a LOT involved in Reliable, so that's why I called your implementation "naive". For instance, your code does not deal with timelyness, if the client misses a message, and no more messages occur for hours...then you are stuffed. You made the classic mistake of thinking, "software, it's easy". Of course it's possible to implement reliable messaging over RTC, but what is the point, you end up with an inner platform effect that isn't maintainable...

Comment: @Mathemats In the interest of full disclosure, those are not my awesome ascii skills, but this nice little tool http://asciiflow.com/ :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

spender's answer is good, but I'd like to address solution 2 in the context of SignalR; you could use the SignalR lifetime events for this: `OnConnected`, `OnReconnected` and `OnDisconnected`. You can read more [about the events here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/hubs-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) and how to [use them in a hub here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-server#connectionlifetime).

You'd fully initialize the view when the client first connects (OnConnected gets called). If a client loses connection temporarily (by default less than 30s, see [relevant settings here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events#disconnecttimeout), `OnReconnected` gets called), you don't need to do anything else; the queued messages will be delivered as long as there is enough space in the standard queuing mechanism.

If the client PC goes to sleep, `OnDisconnected` gets called eventually and the client will have to establish a new connection. At that point, the easiest implementation would be to simply load all data again. If you want to reuse the (outdated) data the client already has, then you'd need

- a way to retrieve a subset of data / messages (e.g. based on a seq number or a timestamp; Since you're already storing the event stream to a DB, it sounds like it should be possible to integrate this)
- store this number on the client whenever it receives a message
- send it to the server when establishing the connection (e.g. via the [query string](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client#querystring)), so that the server can read it in `OnConnected` and knows whether to initialize a full view or only a changeset

Using SignalR messaging for the real-time updates should be fine, however I'd suggest using a regular MVC / WebAPI controller to serve the full dataset necessary to initialize the view (from `OnConnected`).

That said, if you want **guaranteed** delivery, you'll have to ack your messages and probably also implement a queueing mechanism. SignalR only buffers about 1000 messages by default, then it starts dropping them. You can increase that value, but it may make more sense to build one tailored to your requirements.

Comment: Thanks Lars, that's some useful info. I actually did not know about OnReconnected. Marking this as an answer because you stayed within the context of SignalR.

Answer (score 5):

SignalR is not designed for "Reliable Messaging". It was designed for "Real Time Communication".

The issue is that Reliability is in fact incompatible with Real Time. Reliable messaging means that a message will be delivered at least once. However if the data link is down, then the message will be delivered delayed. However Real Time means that the message is delivered "instantly", not half an hour later.

I would switch to a "Message Queue" if reliability is what you need. You should find that they are "quick enough" for your purposes (RTC typically means you need latency in the millisecond range, whilst MQ should give typical latency in the second range).

What your question is asking is, how do I implement a Message Queue over SignalR.

Try RabbitMQ, I've heard only good things with it. There is a Javascript client as well.

Comment: Yes, I do believe your phrasing of my question is better. Actually, I WAS thinking about using RabbitMQ (Redis is mainly there because I was trying out the build MS was keeping in its GitHub repos). But I'm not sure if it's a good idea so use direct JS Client to MQ though. How does the JS client handle disposing of the message queue? When does it decide I'm actually disposing?

Answer (score 4):

So, I think this question is a little too broad and unfocussed, but I've got more to say than will fit in a comment.

In the interest of keeping things simple, I wouldn't use the websocket for communicating the messages themselves, but merely as a notification channel to let clients know that more data is available.

First, I'd concentrate on a means of requesting a limited set of messages via JSON over standard HTTP. I assume that all messages have some sort of sequence number or timestamp, so a client that already has message with stamp `n` will need to be able request all messages with stamp `>n`. Let's call this the message service.

Now connect the websocket and use it to communicate simple "more data available" events to the client. Every time the client receives the event, make a new request to the message service for all messages with stamp > than the most recent that the client has.

If the websocket gets disconnected, when it reconnects, make a separate request to the message service to ensure you're in sync, then wait for events again, as above.

Comment: You're right about the quality of my question. I think Aron's phrasing "How do I implement a Message Queue over SignalR" is better. Regardless, thanks for the useful info, it makes a lot of sense. I'm still unsure how I would go about implementing a means of tracking what info is available for each client though.